# Delphi: How to determine and empty TDatetime value

Tags: delphi, datetime, null, unassigned-variable

Seems there is no way to assign *NULL* (either an "*unassigned value*" to `TDateTime` variables.

The only way I've imagined is using something like this:

```
function isNull(aDate : TDateTime) : boolean;
const NullDate = 0.0;
var aNullDate : TDatetime;
    ms : Int64;
begin
  aNullDate := NullDate;
  ms := MilliSecondsBetween(aDate,aNullDate);
  result := (ms = Int64(0));
end;
```

Is there anybody out who knows better solution what not overlaps 0 date value?

Are negative `TDateTime` values dangerous? (As an able resource for previous purpose)

Comment: If you intend to use this function the was I think, surely `NullDate` should be a global constant?

Comment: I've experienced problems when comparing a zero assigned value TDateTime variable to the const value 0.
A _simple_ **if** as this one didn't check the condition
`    var v_datetime: TDatetime;`
`    v_datetime := 0;` 
`    if (v_datetime = 0) then actionToTake`

Comment: That is because of floating-point fuzz. Use `Math.IsZero`.

Comment: 0 is a perfectly valid date, and negative dates are perfectly fine as well.  0 is midnight on 30 Dec 1899.  Negative numbers are dates before that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As Andreas already wrote, the [`TDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.TDateTime) type is actually `double` and thus not "nullable". I use

```
const
  c_UnassignedDate = -693594;
```

for a empty date value as this represents an impossible date of `00/00/0000`. But for example DevExpress uses

```
NullDate = -700000;
InvalidDate = NullDate + 1;
```

So there seems to be no agreed upon standard vale, you should pick one which suits your need.

Comment: There is no date where **day** and **month** are 0 (zero). In database, if the date is unassigned then `NULL` should be used, not some magic date.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Taking back, I was looking just at the year portion of that date... Well, if the value of a certain date time column will be `NULL` and I would have to store this value strictly to a `TDateTime` field, I would probably use your `c_UnassignedDate` constant value. [+1]

Comment: How do you figure that -693594 represents the date 0/0/0000?

Comment: @Rob: I guess because `-693591` represents `0000-01-03`, `-693592` represents `0000-01-02`, and `-693593` represents `0000-01-01`, at least according to `DateTimeToStr`.

Comment: @RobKennedy just do `ShowMessage(FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy',-693594));` and it pops up dlg with `00.00.0000`.

Comment: @ain: As does every smaller value. My analysis shows that -693594 is the greatest negative integer with this property.

Answer (score 12):

First you need to define what you mean by 'an empty `TDateTime` value'.

A `TDateTime` value is a double with the date encoded in the integer part and the time encoded in the fractional part. So, the closest thing to a 'null date' you can get is probably `0`.

Hence, simply test `ADate <> 0` to test if the date is 'null'.

But beware: if you declare a `TDateTime` local variable then it will not necessarily be `=0` before you give it a value. It can be anything. Of course, the same thing applies to variables of type `integer`, `double`, `boolean`, ...

Also, I believe that a `TDateTime` with value `0` encodes the date 1899-12-30.

Finally, negative `TDateTime` values are perfectly normal. For instance, `-5000` corresponds to `1886-04-22`.

I don't quite get the point of your code. If you want to use `0` as the 'unassigned' value (which is bad if you are interested in dates close to 1899-12-30), why not do simply

```
function IsUnassigned(ADate: TDateTime): boolean;
begin
  result := ADate = 0;
end;
```

or, possibly (but not equivalently!),

```
function IsUnassigned(ADate: TDateTime): boolean;
begin
  result := IsZero(Date);
end;
```

In his answer, ain gave a couple of more reasonable choices for the 'unassigned date' value.

Comment: Negative time dates become meaningless eventually, when the calendar breaks.

Comment: @David: Good point. So there are actually plenty of plausible choices for the 'unsassigned' value.

Comment: Would it not be useful to use NaN as an explicit value here? You can then use IsNaN to test for the condition.

Answer (score 4):

At unit `Spring.Persistence.Core.Session.pas` of library *Spring Framework for Delphi* (http://www.spring4d.org) in method `TSession.ExecuteScalar<T>` in case of NULL for result used value `Default(T);`

I think, Your function can look like

```
function IsNull(ADate: TDateTime): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ADate = Default(TDateTime);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PDateTime instead TDateTime, and send as nil value. If no pointer to value, result no value.

To check value use Assigned ptr :

```
MyDatePointer := nil;
if ( Assigned(MyDatePointer)) then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

tDateTime is undefined for the values between 0 and -1 which means that a tDateTime of -0.5 is an undefined value and useful for a null date as an alternative to NaN. DateTimeToString will display -0.5 the same as +0.5;